# unable to install rosserial on my laptop

Tags: rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ankit@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install rosserial_python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rosserial_python

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135591/unable-to-install-rosserial-on-my-laptop/) by [anantsarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/12541/anantsarin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS debs are prefixed with 'ros-{distro}-' and have underscores replaces with dashes (a limitation of the deb naming rules).

On Hydro, try installing rosserial as:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rosserial-python
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3